# AS3: Is looping a Tweenlite class efficient

Tags: actionscript-3, easing, gsap

I have a game for Android, in which I'm looping a tweenlite class so that object moves smoothly. I know I should make my own smoothing function to move objects, but I guess I'm not doing it better than tweenlite. In the Code, I'm following the ball as it is rolled, and I wanna do it in particular easing manner. This code does not run continuously, it only runs for few seconds each time after ball is rolled.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate_object);

public function animate_object(e:Event):void
{
    var move_screen = obj_distance * ( obj_active + (Game.Ball.ball_taps + 1)) - 2);
    TweenLite.to(Object_Container, 1, {y:move_screen ,ease:Quad.easeInOut});
}
```

My Question, Is it efficient for me to use it like that when doing it for Android?

Comment: Why use an enterframe function if you ask it every frame to make your ball roll for 1 second in the Tween ?

Is it for updating the target position depending on the time elasped ? Because I'm not sure starting overwriting Tweens everyframe can do any good... :-)

Comment: @bertrand.riche Hmm, you are right, then I should use timer, every half second so that tween animation ease is not broken.

Comment: if you want to lopp the tweenlite animation you could trigger a function when the animation is completed

Comment: @Nicholas Yes, but it doesn't work in my case, I have to maintain the easing while the object is moving.